# How to take IFFT of Connes Window?

Tags: matlab, fft, discrete-signals, fourier-transform

The Connes Window function is defined as :

> w(f)=$(1-(\frac{f}{ \Delta f})^2)^2$     for $f<|\Delta f| $
>
> w(f)=0         otherwise

The inverse fourier transform of this function can be analytically calculated to be a purely real valued function.

However performing IFFT using matlab gives me a complex function whith real and imaginary parts.
The code I used in the following:

```
delta_f=10;

fs=300; 

nCyl = 5;

t=0:1/fs:nCyl*1/f;

x=(1-(t/delta_f).^2).^2;

plot(t,x);

NFFT=1024;  
 
X=fftshift(ifft(x,NFFT));       

fVals=fs*(-NFFT/2:NFFT/2-1)/NFFT;   
 
plot(fVals,real(X),'b');
```

I think this discrepancy has something to do with the function being piecewise.
Is there something which I am missing?

Comment: is the last sample equal to the first sample?  it shouldn't be.  it should be cyclic.  `ifft([1,2,3,4,3,2,1])` is complex but `ifft([1,2,3,4,3,2])` is real

Comment: no it still gives imaginary values.but why does that happen to the example you gave? shouldnt the same function same inverse fourier transform?

Comment: `[1,2,3,4,3,2]` is symmetrical, with the first sample occurring right after the last sample.  So is `[1,0,0,2,0,0]`, for instance. Anything of the form `[a,b,c,d,e,d,c,b]` will have a real transform.